# php inside javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

why does the following code not work?

```
<?php
$j= "<option value='kj' name='dd'>" ;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getinfo(a){     
    if(a==2){
    var k ="<?php echo $j;?>";
    alert(k);
    }


}
</script>
```

It works when I say $j="option";

Comment: Any errors? Have you checked your page's generated source? What does it say in there?

Comment: Well it does not show the alert box so I assume it's not working

Comment: You need to debug it. Is your function even being called? Do you have any errors in your console? What does your generated source show?

Comment: FYI, whenever you have a PHP variable you want to use in JavaScript use `json_encode($var)` instead of echoing it into quotes.

Comment: @ThiefMaster For my own edification, why is that advisable?

Comment: What is it supposed to display? And what exactly is it displaying?

Comment: @thatidiotguy will work regardless of variable type, easier and less error prone than concatenation

Comment: @Xeon06 Does that require json deserialization on the javascript end, or will that be done automatically?

Comment: @thatidiotguy, you'll need to json deserialize it.

Comment: @thatidiotguy "JSON" is always valid JavaScript (vice-versa not always applicable). As such, encoding a variable as "JSON" on the PHP side simply ensures it will be displayed properly in the code in JS

Comment: @sam no you won't, in the context of putting a value in a JS variable from PHP, you don't need to do any deserialization in the JS. It will be the value as-is.

Comment: @Xeon06 When you json_encode, the result will be an object; you can either use it that way (if you can work with objects), or de-serialize it as an array, and work with it likewise.

Comment: @sam We are talking about generating JavaScript code here. See this example. http://codepad.org/xJddKcDz The resulting output is valid JavaScript without any deserialization

Comment: @Xeon06; if you are going to generate data via json_encode, chances are the data will be more complex than those examples shown. Letting a relatively new JS developer know that they might need to convert the data from object to an array is important; otherwise, it might create much confusion for them. Are you correct? Yes. Will that work everytime? Absolutely not, especially if you are expecting an array.

Comment: @sam I'm sorry, I don't understand where deserialization would ever be necessary in this. Can you show me an example?

Comment: @Xeon06; here's an example: http://codepad.org/XGUP55VG; to work with that data, novice developers might decide to use eval, which is risky. You don't have to always deserialize, but sometimes, you do.

Comment: @It'sYourFault Okay sorry, I was rethinking about this, and it still doesn't make sense. Maybe we're just arguing the same thing in different words. What I'm saying is, in NO case at all, will JSON *require* deserialization. It is always valid JavaScript. http://codepad.org/jEyq8PPj

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple possibilities here:

1) getInfo is never called.

2) a is never equal to 2

3) There are errors in other javascript code on your page.

EDIT 4): Other people have pointed out that the content of $j may not be allowed in an alert box.

There is no way for anyone here to tell which it is.

Comment: +1 W/o seeing how/if getInfo is called, this is unanswerable.